# Why is my property tester invoked when selecting text in editor?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, popup

In my eclipse plugin that I'm writing I want to be able to make a popup menu contribution to be visible or not depending on the content on the current selected row in the editor.

To accomplice this I use a property tester. The test performed by the property tester can be a bit time consuming (~ 200 miliseconds) which is ok when it comes to waiting for the popup menu to show.

However I've noticed that the property tester is not only invoked when the popup is about to be shown, but it is also invoked as soon as I'm marking text in the editor making selection of text very slow and annoying.

So the questions are: Why is it invoked when I select/mark text and not just when the popup is about to be shown, and how can I avoid that ?

This is how I've set up the property tester and the menu:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
  <propertyTester 
        class="popupmenucontribtest.PropertyTester"
        id="PopupMenuContribTest.test1"
        namespace="PopupMenuContribTest.propertyTester"
        properties="propertyTester1"
        type="java.lang.Object">
  </propertyTester>
```

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
<menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
     <command
           commandId="PopupMenuContribTest.command"
           label="My Popup Option"
           style="push">
        <visibleWhen
              checkEnabled="false">
           <and>
              <test
                 forcePluginActivation="true"
                 property="PopupMenuContribTest.propertyTester.propertyTester1">
              </test>
           </and>
        </visibleWhen>
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You specified that property tester to be invoked for every instance of `java.lang.Object`, using the `type` attribute in your definition. Restrict this to a more concrete super class of your editor. See [this example](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_expressions_propertyTesters.html), where it is restricted to resources.

That said, to my mind a property test duration of 200 milli seconds is not acceptable, as users will notice such delays.